# How to increase the web service timeout to a larger value so that publishing a large infopath form to SharePoint library can be successful?

Tags: document-library, infopath, form

Currently, publishing of large SharePoint Form library may result in 'Updating Content Type Failed' message. According to this [article](http://doolbox.blogspot.in/2008/09/publishing-infopath-forms-updating.html), it mention that increasing the web service timeout to larger than 30 seconds.

So, how do I set this setting at which part of the SharePoint Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{Root Drive}:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories{Web Application Port}
in that directory you will find web.config file, you should be able to change time out values in that xml file

their are lots of timeout properties so you will have to experiment with each one to find the one you are looking for.

you can also change things like message sizes etc

Kind Regards